# Right usage of requestAnimationFrame / cancelAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, structure, requestanimationframe

While working with the **requestAnimationFrame API**, I encountered a problem.
It might be because the **structure** I use is wrong, but it seems logical to me.

What I basically do is a very easy background-position manipulation for an infinite falling effect:

( This version is simplified, but demonstrative )

```
cache.mechanism.snowFall = function(){

    cache.snow.position.y ++;
    if( cache.snow.position.y > cache.viewport.height ){ 
        cache.snow.position.y -= cache.viewport.height; 
    }
    cache.snow.elem.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + cache.snow.position.y + "px";

    requestAnimationFrame( cache.mechanism.snowFall );

};
```

Actually, it moves the background position 1px lower with every animation frame. 
( Resets when neccessary, to avoid high paint times, and FPS loss )

I initialize it by calling:

```
cache.mechanism.snowFall();
```

So, it runs fine, with a very high FPS, but it is not possible to stop it.

```
cancelAnimationFrame( cache.mechanism.snowFall );
```

-does nothing, and returns undefined.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should send the id of the `requestAnimationFrame` you want to cancel into `cancelAnimationFrame`.  That id is a return value of the original `requestAnimationFrame`.

So request one animation loop:

```
var id = requestAnimationFrame(cache.mechanism.snowFall);
```

And to cancel that request:

```
cancelAnimationFrame(id);
```

Alternatively, since `requestAnimationFrame` must be called to keep the loop running, you could use a flag to stop the animation:

```
// Set an external flag to allow animations to continue
var continueAnimating = true;

function animate()
{
    if(continueAnimating)
    {
        // when continueAnimating is false, this new
        // request will not occur and animation stops
        requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
    }
}

// To turn off animation
continueAnimating = false;
```